# Can you sync one individual folder between two GIT Repos?

Tags: git, github

So I'm using two development remote GIT repos at work, each repo has its own purpose with its own set of folders and files and such.

For example, something like this

REPO1

```
Folder A
Folder B
Folder C
```

REPO2

```
Folder C
Folder D
Folder E
```

So Folder C is the same folder in both repo's, it holds the same files etc. All new development work is done in `REPO1` for folder C, and about once a week someone goes in and manually merges all the latest changes from `REPO1` Folder C to `REPO2` Folder C.

This means that `REPO2` is always a little out of date for Folder C. So is it possible to sync just Folder C automatically for every commit from `REPO1` to `REPO2`, without affecting any other folders in each repo, as those are different and need to remain that way?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like what you're looking for is submodules. Basically the idea is:

- Create a new repo with the content of `Folder C`
- Reference this new repo as a submodule both in `REPO1` and `REPO2`
- When you'll work in the `Folder C` of the `REPO1` it will actually update this new repo
- You'll then just have to update this submoule in `REPO2`

You should have a look at http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules to get started.

---

If we're talking about a repo of code, an easier solution could be:

- Create a library (eg: a maven package if you're using java) out of `Folder C` sources
- Remove `Folder C` from `REPO2`. Instead, add a reference to this library
- Then, you'd just have to publish a new version of this library when you want to update it in `REPO2`

The downside is that it may not be easy (or even possible) to put that in place. However, if you can, it will be much easier afterwards.