# Automatically pull from another repo (when pushed) then update

Tags: git, github, version-control, updates

**Problem:**

I have two repo's, one (repo A) contains scss files (folder named scss) that I would like to use in repo B.

In repo B I would like to add the scss folder as a subdirectory, and when I make a push to repo A, the scss folder should automatically pull in the contents and make a push.

Basically I need the folders to have the exactly the same contents at all times, Im presuming above is the only way to do so?

**Tried:**

Thought about git hooks for this but I'm under the impression that they're best used on a server, and currently they are two local repo's sitting on my computer.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search came up with an interesting tool called [GitHubSync](https://github.com/SimonCropp/GitHubSync)
 that might help you synchronize specific files and folders across different Github repositories. It doesn't seem to work for other platforms so you will need to look for a different solution if you repositories are not hosted on Github.

**Edit**: Also take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23285151/5759072) that talks about Git submodules that does exactly what you want to do using references, and the official Git [documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) about submodules.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. I will have a look at the link. I've heard submodules can be difficult to maintain and hard to implement though. I'm not sure if this technique will automatically keep the folders on sync on repo b too?

Comment: Are these hypothetical repositories under the same parent folder?

Comment: They can be if needed. I'm pulling in SCSS files and CSS files into a laravel build.

Comment: I would suggest trying it out with two test repos with one or two files under the same parent directory and see if you can make them sync up using the methods I gave you in my answer. If that works you can move from there to implement a more complex system.